# Saving a BigDecimal value to json

Tags: android, json, bigdecimal

new to the site and Android programming so I hope someone can help me out. I am trying to self teach and would consider myself a bit of a noob. Right now I'm more of a consumer of this site, but hopefully can become a contributor.

I have created an EditText within a Fragment where I want to capture a dollar amount / currency value. I am trying to use a BigDecimal but am having a hard time implementing. I have a Class named Transaction where I defined getters and setters as well as my JSON object. For example my getters and setters are implemented:

```
public BigDecimal getAmount() {
    return mAmount;
}   

public void setAmount(BigDecimal amount) {
    mAmount = amount;
}
```

and my JSON to Save and Retrieve looks like:

```
json.put(JSON_AMOUNT, mAmount);



if (json.has(JSON_AMOUNT)) {
        mAmount = BigDecimal.valueOf(json.getDouble(JSON_AMOUNT));
}
```

In my OnCreateView of my fragment, my EditText looks like:

```
mAmountField = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.transaction_amount);
     mAmountField.setText((CharSequence) mTransaction.getAmount());
     mAmountField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

         DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

         public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
             if (!s.toString().matches("\\$(d{1,3}(\\,\\d{3})*|(\\d+))(\\.\\d{2})?$")) {
                 String userInput = "" + s.toString().replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
                 if (userInput.length() > 0) {
                     Float in = Float.parseFloat(userInput);
                     float percent = in/100;
                     mAmountField.setText("$" + dec.format(percent));
                     mAmountField.setSelection(mAmountField.getText().length());
                 }

                 mTransaction.setAmount(BigDecimal.valueOf());

                }

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }

        });
```

What I can't figure out is how to save the value entered for mAmountField to my JSON Object. With Strings I just use (For Example):

```
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        mTransaction.setDetails(s.toString());
    }
```

But I can't figure out the correct syntax for a BigDecimal. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're using the standard org.json library for Android, the only number types are Long or Double. If Double will give you suitable precision then just use that. Alternatively you may need to use the `toString()` method in order to simply write the value as a String.

Comment: Just for reference, there is a commit to the master branch of the json.org library that adds [BigInteger and BigDecimal support](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/pull/135), so expect it in a future release.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save BigDecimal as string to JsonObject you need to use the toString()

```
json.put(JSON_AMOUNT, mAmount.toString());
```

and then when you want to get the value back

```
BigDecimal mAmount= new BigDecimal(json.optString(JSON_AMOUNT,"0"));
```

ps. you can use getString() instead optString() but I recommend optString() because you can set the default value is the key is not exist.

Another suggestion is using [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library to convert between json and value, you will can serialize whole object and deserialize it back.